# How to install skyrim using wine?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam, wine

I used the following commands from

to install skyrim on linux using wine

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo rm -rf ~/.wine
WINEARCH=win32 wineboot --update
sudo apt-get install curl (optional)
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.7-i386 (might be required on x86 systems)
sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
winetricks --no-isolate steam
```

however I keep getting stuck in the Alduin loading screen with a resource management error. I tried re-running the game a second time to copy down the error from the terminal, but I honestly do not know what the terminal command is to run skyrim. I tried the following command and received the following error

```
$ wine steam
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\steam.exe"
```

Does anyone know the proper way to install skyrim using wine on linux? I also tried Playonliux and received a similar issue.

Skyrim running on Playonlinux below? Still laggy and unable to enter and exit skyrim smoothly without force quieting.

```
$ playonlinux steam
Looking for python... 2.7.3 - selected
[main] Message: PlayOnLinux (4.2.2) is starting
[clean_tmp] Message: Cleaning temp directory
[Check_OpenGL] Message: 32bits direct rendering is enabled
[Check_OpenGL] Message: 64bits direct rendering is enabled
[POL_System_CheckFS] Message: Checking filesystem for /home/gin/.PlayOnLinux/
[main] Message: Filesystem is compatible
gin@ger:~$ playonlinux
Looking for python... 2.7.3 - selected
[main] Message: PlayOnLinux (4.2.2) is starting
[clean_tmp] Message: Cleaning temp directory
[Check_OpenGL] Message: 32bits direct rendering is enabled
[Check_OpenGL] Message: 64bits direct rendering is enabled
[POL_System_CheckFS] Message: Checking filesystem for /home/gin/.PlayOnLinux/
[main] Message: Filesystem is compatible
[install_plugins] Message: Checking plugin: Capture...
[install_plugins] Message: Checking plugin: ScreenCap...
[install_plugins] Message: Checking plugin: PlayOnLinux Vault...
[maj_check] Message: Web version : 1400470683
[maj_check] Message: Current local version : 1400139386
[maj_check] Message: Updating list
[POL_Config_Write] Message: Config write: LAST_TIMESTAMP 1400470683
[POL_System_CheckFS] Message: Checking filesystem for Steam.exe
[POL_Wine] Message: Running wine-1.5.25 Steam.exe (Working directory : /home/gin/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Steam/drive_c/Program Files/Steam)
[POL_Wine] Message: Notice: PlayOnLinux deliberately disables winemenubuilder. See http://www.playonlinux.com/fr/page-26-Winemenubuilder.html
[0519/122746:ERROR:resource_bundle.cc(417)] Failed to load C:\Program Files\Steam\bin\chrome.pak
Some features may not be available.
[0519/122746:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(126)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 8
[0519/122813:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(126)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 8
[0519/122821:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(126)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 8
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 72850
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198072153712 [API loaded no]
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 72850
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198072153712 [API loaded no]
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 72850
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198072153712 [API loaded no]
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 72850
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198072153712 [API loaded no]
[0519/122950:ERROR:resource_bundle.cc(417)] Failed to load C:\Program Files\Steam\bin\chrome.pak
Some features may not be available.
[0519/122950:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(126)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 8
^CSetting breakpad minidump AppID = 72850
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198072153712 [API loaded no]
^C^C^C^C[POL_Wine] Message: Wine return: 1
[POL_SetupWindow_Init] Message: Creating new window for pid 8711
^C^C
Ctrl+C pressed. Killing all processes...
```

Comment: Oh, hey, SE now supports embedded YouTube videos?

Comment: It seems wine is trying to load steam from the wrong directory (C:\\windows\\system32\\steam.exe), try giving it the full path, though I don't know exactly where to find that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use wine. use PlayOnLinux

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

It's an easier way to install anything for linux that wasn't made for linux. It was recently updated to [support Skyrim](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/commentaires-1047.html).

Comment: Thats great! thanks fredley!!!!!!!!!!!! Kudos to you man! :):):)

Comment: how should I fix my playonlinux installation? I cannot get it to load the game.

Comment: Sorry man I really need help. I have been stuck with attempting to run skyrim on playonlinux. I am desperate for help.

Comment: Get the linux version of it. I can see that you have it on steam, make sure you have the linux version of steam and let steam install skyrim. you dont need to use WINE or PoL to install skyrim anymore :)

Comment: @Jonathan Except that there's no Linux version of Skyrim, and Linux Steam won't let you install non-Linux games through it. You still need wine/POL.

Comment: I did some research and i think you may be right :( there isn't skyrim on linux. try this link and see if you get any troubles, if you get stuck, throw in some screen shots of errors or tell us where you get stuck and we can help you :)

Comment: Oh and go check out this link! http://www.gamersonlinux.com/forum/threads/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim-guide.331/

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial works perfectly for me.
I'm playing Skyrim for Steam flawless!

But to run steam you should use the following command:

> $ nohup wine "/home/USER/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Steam/Steam.exe" &

This will make you terminal free for closing after Steam started.

Or you can just run [Yet, you can make a skyrim.desktop file for this command]:

> $ wine "/home/USER/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Steam/Steam.exe"

I hope this help.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the answer. 3 questions: Are you able to use mods using the mod organizer? What is your game play video quality like? Have you experienced any video lag during combat?